# Designing a for loop with specifically named items

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop, coding-style, graphical-interaction

I often run into this situation when writing code for a GUI and would like to know would be a best-practice way of solving this. The situation is this:

I have a number of identical items on my GUI which have different variable names, i.e. I have 10 'identical' buttons which are named Button1, Button2, Button3, etc...

The buttons' displayed text is updated in the code and I want to check when they are updated if they meet a certain condition and then change the text color based on that condition. So for button1 I would write:

```
if (Button1.text == "true"){
    Button1.textcolor = blue}
else if (Button1.text == "false"){
    Button1.textcolor = red}
```

Now it seems redundant to have to write this code again for each of the 10 buttons, replacing Button1's variable name with Button2's and so on up until Button10. Is there a way to change the "Button1" part of the code in a loop and keep everything else the same? So a pseudo-code example of what I'm looking for would be:

```
for (all buttons in (button1-button10)){
    if (thisbutton.text == "true"){
        thisbutton.textcolor = blue}
    else if (thisbutton.text == "false"){
        thisbutton.textcolor = red}}
```

I don't know how to best approach this scenario and would appreciate input and guidance on this.

Thanks

Comment: There are many ways, but depending on your setup one could be way better than the other. Are you using WinForms? Where are those button declared?

Comment: @Uno I'm using Wpf in C# - I add the buttons in Visual Studio graphically and then can reference them in my code. I believe they are declared in the GUI's xaml code.

Comment: You should update your question tags to include WPF. My answer is for winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a set of similar objects don´t create a variable for every instance of those objects, instead put them into one single collection. Then you can easily loop this list and manipulate the objects within it:

```
var buttons = new List<Button>();

// put the buttons into the list using buttons.Add

for (var b in buttons)
{
    if (b.text == "true")
    {
        b.textcolor = blue
    }
    else 
    {
        b.textcolor = red
    }
}
```

You can also use a `GridView` to put all those buttons into a ragular grid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems like a nice solution. I wonder if there might be a way to do it "on-the-fly" without creating a special object for it? I am still new to C# and wonder if there's a way to loop through different objects and not use a special container? Thanks

Comment: Of course you *could* do this by reflection when your buttons are members of your class (not just variables within a method!!). However you *should not*. You won´t need 10 variables for 10 instances, all you need instead is *one* list holding those 10 instances.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own button.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class TheButton : Button
    {
        public void ChangeColor()
        {
            ForeColor = (Text == "true")  ? Color.Blue : Color.Red ;

        }
    }
}
```

Rebuild your solution, and you should see TheButton in the toolbox, in your form, Add a container class, like a panel, and add your instances of TheButton class.

You could then write a method, like:

```
    private void ChangeAllButtons()
    {
        foreach (var control in panel1.Controls.Cast<object>().Where(control => (control as TheButton) != null))
        {
            (control as TheButton).ChangeColor();
        }
    }
```

You will have to decide the best place to call ChangeAllButtons().

Comment: Thanks for your response, this also seems like a viable solution. Your foreach loop is interesting as it seems I might be able to loop through the objects which are in the parent object of the buttons and operate on them in similar fashion to your example. I will have to look into foreach loops in more detail.

Comment: Does WPF have .Controls? Are you thinking of WinForms? I can't see this property in my assembly.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to approach this.

As the buttons are created by the designer as fields of the window/panel, to list them you have to analyse the **WPF** tree (or use reflection on the main window panel which it's not really elegant).

To get all the `Button` children you can use this method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EnumVisualOfType<T>(Visual visual) where T : Visual
{
    for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(visual); i++)
    {
        var visualChild = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(visual, i);

        foreach (var child in EnumVisualOfType<T>(visualChild))
            yield return child;

        var childVisual = visualChild as T;

        if (childVisual != null)
            yield return childVisual;
    }
}
```

And then invoke it:

```
var allButtons = EnumVisualOfType<Button>(window).ToList();
```

And you have the list of all the buttons (which you can, of course, filter on a specific property if you like) and you can write your code once and use it in a foreach loop.

You can also explicitly add all your buttons to a list when the panel is created, but then you will have to remember to add them manually every time you create a new one.